# Predictable UIDs of users created in the process of portage package installation

Tags: gentoo, uid, portage

Adding users is specified in portage ebuild files using the `enewuser` function. Some ebuilds call this function with a specific UID (second argument), others either don't provide the argument or specify -1 which has the same effect. In the latter cases some free UID (presumably the next free one on the system) is used which makes it impossible to keep the UIDs in sync across systems.

Is there a mechanism in portage to achieve consistent UIDs across systems? E.g. providing portage with a database of "username - UID" combinations and having it override the default behavior of `enewuser` in a way as to enforce this mapping when creating new users?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience on Gentoo, but I'd test what happens if the user account that the package would create already exists.

If the package will accept a pre-existing account, simply find out what username(s) a package needs, then pre-create the user(s) on all your systems with matching UIDs before installing the package.

Comment: (with the same settings for the shell and for group membership, and the "comment" (user description) wouldn't hurt either)